# Command to convert Hex to decimal in Linux?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm trying to convert the hexadecimal value to a decimal value in my map file. For example, here is a snippet of the file

```
.bss       0xc     g2.comms
.bss       0xc     g2.comms
.bss       0xa     g2.comms
.bss       0x14    g2.comms
.rodata    0x64    g2.comms
.rodata    0x1ac   g2.comms
.rodata    0x270   g2.comms
.rodata    0x18    g2.comms
```

Is there a one line command that can convert the 2nd column from hexadecimal to decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU awk (gawk):

```
$ awk -n '{print $2+0}' file
12
12
10
20
100
428
624
24
```

`-n` (or `--non-decimal-data`) causes "the automatic interpretation of octal and hexadecimal values in input data."  In order to make sure that awk treats the second column as a number, not a string, we add zero to it: `$2+0`.